Change value to a renamed activeX checkbock vba
I need to change the value of a renamed activeX checkbox ("cbZinc"). I've wrote the following code that I found in an old post but it doesn't work. I'm sure that it has to be something quite easy, but I can't find the proper code.
Sub TEST()

    'Set worksheets "Data"
        Dim wsData As Worksheet
        Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'change name of sheet
       
    'Change checkbox value
    wsData.OLEObjects("cbZinc").Object.Value = True


End Sub 


"it doesn't work" meaning you got an error, the output wasn't as expected, or what?

Yes, I got a method error of OLEObjects (error 1004). Do you know how could I call the renamed checkbox instead?

Seems that you're using either the incorrect name or calling an object on the incorrect sheet.  You could loop through the OLEObjects on the given sheet and confirm the name; i suspect you would be able to quickly check with which sheet you're working.

Your code should work as is. Try to save and close the workbook. If it still doesn't work, list the names of all ActiveX controls on the worksheet in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) with the following code: Dim ole As OLEObject: For Each ole In wsData.OLEObjects: If ole.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then: Debug.Print ole.Name: End If: Next ole. Each colon denotes a new line. Save and close the workbook before running the code.
